# Getting text from buttons in an array then concating all the values into a string

Tags: java, button, javafx, arraylist

I have a list of buttons that I use as tiles for my tic tac toe game and I want to make a method to check for a tie which would basically check if the board is full and there is no winner then it is a tie.

I want to grab the text from all the buttons and concat it all into 1 string and when that string's length is 9 and there isn't a winner then it is a tie.

my current method works but I was wondering if there's anyway to be more efficient with it by either using a loop or something

code for initializing the game

```
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        buttons = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7,button8,button9));
        buttons.forEach(button ->{
            setupButton(button);
            button.setFocusTraversable(false);
            button.setText("");
        });
    }
```

code to check for tie

```
line2 = button1.getText() + button2.getText() + button3.getText() + button4.getText() + button5.getText() + button6.getText() + button7.getText() + button8.getText() + button9.getText();

            if ((line2.length()) == 9 && winner == null) {
            ties++;
            tiesText.setText(""+ties);
            disableAllButtons();
            newGame(null);
            }
```

Comment: Just something to consider: It’s a tie if every line contains both an O and an X. The lines are (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9), (1,4,7), (2,5,8), (3,6,9), (1,5,9), (3,5,7). That way you can actually detect a guaranteed tie before all the squares are filled.

Comment: Damn that's interesting I never really thought of ties like that. But this will be useful for my player vs computer version of the game. Thanks James.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a counter and increment it on button click. If the counter is 9 it's a tie.

If you want sticking to the buttontext you can use a foreach loop like :

```
line2 = "";
foreach (Button button : buttons){
  line2 += button.getText();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a listener on a concatenated string binding, then use that to monitor the concatenated text of all buttons.

For example:

```
StringExpression state = Bindings.concat(
        board.getChildren().stream()
                .map(node -> ((Button) node).textProperty())
                .toArray()
);
state.addListener((observable, oldState, newState) ->
        handleStateChange(newState)
);
```

This might be a little bit more complicated than necessary.  For a basic solution, it is just fine to react to the button clicks and update the state there in a loop (as in [valentin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70347445/1155209)), rather than using a binding.  But the binding does provide an alternate solution, keeping your original concept of concatenating button text.

An example of a String value which represents the `newState` would be a nine character string:

```
"XO  XO  X"
```

In this example, unplayed squares are spaces, and X has just won by a diagonal line from top-left to bottom-right.

[image: game]

**Example in context**

- Uses James' suggestion of checking lines for tie detection.
- Uses Java 17 features.

App code

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.beans.binding.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class NoughtsAndCrosses extends Application {
    private static final int NUM_SQUARES = 9;

    private static final String X = "X";
    private static final String O = "O";
    private static final String TIE = "-";
    private static final String NONE = " ";

    private String nextPlayer = X;

    private Scene scene;

    private static final int[][] LINES = {
            {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9},  // horizontal
            {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {3,6,9},  // vertical
            {1,5,9}, {3,5,7}            // diagonal
    };

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        scene = new Scene(newGame());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Noughts and Crosses");
        stage.show();
    }

    private Parent newGame() {
        TilePane board = createBoard();
        if (scene != null) {
            scene.setRoot(board);
        }

        return board;
    }

    private TilePane createBoard() {
        TilePane board = new TilePane(10, 10);
        board.setStyle("-fx-base: antiquewhite; -fx-font-size: 30; -fx-font-weight: bold;");
        board.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        board.setPrefColumns(3);
        board.setMinSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        board.setMaxSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SQUARES; i++) {
            board.getChildren().add(createSquare());
        }

        StringExpression state = Bindings.concat(
                board.getChildren().stream()
                        .map(node -> ((Button) node).textProperty())
                        .toArray()
        );
        state.addListener((observable, oldState, newState) ->
                handleStateChange(newState)
        );

        return board;
    }

    private Button createSquare() {
        final Button square = new Button(NONE);
        square.setMinSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        square.setPrefSize(65, 65);
        square.setMaxSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        square.setOnAction(e -> takeTurn(square));

        return square;
    }

    private void takeTurn(Button square) {
        square.setText(nextPlayer);
        nextPlayer = X.equals(nextPlayer) ? O : X;
    }

    private void handleStateChange(String state) {
        int nTies = 0;

        for (int[] line : LINES) {
            String result = checkResult(line, state);
            switch (result) {
                case X -> { endGame(X); return; }
                case O -> { endGame(O); return; }
                case TIE -> nTies++;
            }
        }

        if (nTies == LINES.length) {
            endGame(TIE);
        }
    }

    private String checkResult(int[] line, String state) {
        int numX = 0, numO = 0;

        for (int j : line) {
            String cellState = state.substring(j - 1, j);
            switch (cellState) {
                case X -> numX++;
                case O -> numO++;
            }
        }

        if (numX == 3) {
            return X;
        }

        if (numO == 3) {
            return O;
        }

        if (numX > 0 && numO > 0) {
            return TIE;
        }

        return NONE;
    }

    private void endGame(String result) {
        String msg = switch (result) {
            case X -> X + " won";
            case O -> O + " won";
            case TIE -> "Tie";
            default -> "unexpected result";
        };

        Alert resultDialog = new Alert(
                Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION,
                """
                Play again?
                
                %s will start first.
                """.formatted(X.equals(nextPlayer) ? O : X)
        );
        resultDialog.setHeaderText(msg);
        resultDialog.setTitle("Game Over");

        resultDialog.initOwner(
                scene.getWindow()
        );

        // we do this in a run later as we want the board state to update for
        // the last interaction before displaying the result dialog.
        Platform.runLater(() ->
            resultDialog.showAndWait()
                    .filter(response -> response == ButtonType.OK)
                    .ifPresentOrElse(
                            response -> newGame(),
                            Platform::exit
                    )
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```